# security issues with JSON.parse

Tags: json, security

Are there any security issues with using JSON.parse() to parse json data?  If the json comes from an untrusted or malicious source, is there a security risk in the JSON.parse() call itself?

Note I am not talking about:

- Attacks on a particular implementation of JSON.parse, like buffer overflows or the like.
- getting information by snooping on the json contents.
- Getting the rest of the app do do something bad because it didn't sanity check the retrieved data.

Answer (score 0):

No. It's just a data structure. Security wise only implementation matters (which you excluded)